# Parsing a String id with SugarORM and GSON

Tags: android, json, gson, sugarorm

I'm using `GSON` to create a `SugarRecord` object from a json response. The API I'm using returns a field called "id", but the type of "id" is a string, not a long (the backend is using mongo).

Below is the code I'm using:

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); // Or use new GsonBuilder().create();
NutritionPlan target = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.getJSONObject("nutrition_day").toString(), NutritionPlan.class);
```

Below is my json response:

```
{
"nutrition_day": {
    "id": "5342b4163865660012ab0000",
    "start_on": "2014-04-08",
    "protein_target": 157,
    "sodium_limit": 2000
}
```

Is there a good way to handle this scenario? I tried

```
@Ignore 
long id;
```

and

```
@SerializedName("id")
String nutrition_plan_id;
```

in my model, but neither helped. Anyone familiar with [Sugar ORM](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/creation.html), and know how to deal with an `id` field that isn't a long?

Comment: why don't you take `long id` out of your model?

Comment: tried that. the long type of the id automatically comes from SugarRecord. I'm trying to overwrite it and change it to a string type

Answer (score 4):

Replace the key "id" in the string to be "nutrition_day_id".
You can use the id json and the id sql.

```
jsonObject.getJSONObject("nutrition_day").toString().replace("\"id\"","\"nutrition_day_id\"")
```

Answer (score 1):

It helped me to change `id` name to `mid` and add annotation `@Expose` to all fields which have to be serialized and add annotation `@SerializedName` to new `id` field.

```
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private final String mid;

@Expose
private final String street;
```

Answer (score 1):

No big changes need be made.

Just use **transient** statement before **Long** type.

```
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private transient Long id;
```

Then, if you have **getId** and **setId** methods, should delete them.

And have fun!

Answer (score 0):

I've been concerned with the same problem, and the only solution i've found was to rename the id name from my API. From example try to send nutrition_plan_id instead of id from your API and it would done the job.

Comment: The only issue is, I'm using a third party API, so I can't change the id.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, but it won't be the best.

I just ignored `id` in my Feed

```
public class Feed extends SugarRecord<Feed>  {

  @Expose int idMember;
}
```

It works fine, however the real `id` is no more used.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution to this problem for quite some time. Finally I found a solution to it. Simply add `@Table` annotation to the desired class instead of extending it from `SugarRecord` and manually add `id` attribute. You can exclude it from Gson serialization via `transient` keyword, or/and rename it, with `@SerializedName` annotation.

Example (works fine for me on SugarOrm v1.4):

```
@Table
public class MySugarOrmClass{

    @SerializedName("db_id")
    private transient Long id = null;

    @SerializedName("id")
    private Integer aid;

    // Add an empty constructor
    public MySugarClass(){}


    //Other fields and class attributes
    ...
}
```

But this means that you cannot use `.save(), .delete()`, etc. methods on this class. Instead you have to use SugarRecord's static methods:
`SugarRecord.save(), SugarRecord.delete()`,...