# Conflict with sugar orm and gson

Tags: android, sugarcrm, retrofit2, gson

My Model looks simplified something like this

```
@Table
public class Movie extends SugarRecord implements Parcelable {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Long movieId;
@SerializedName("adult")
@Expose
private Boolean adult;
@SerializedName("backdrop_path")
@Expose
private String backdropPath;
@SerializedName("genre_ids")
@Expose
private List<Integer> genreIds = new ArrayList<>();
@SerializedName("original_language")
@Expose
private String originalLanguage;
@SerializedName("original_title")
@Expose
private String originalTitle;
@SerializedName("overview")
@Expose
private String overview;
@SerializedName("release_date")
@Expose
private String releaseDate;
@SerializedName("poster_path")
@Expose
private String posterPath;
@SerializedName("popularity")
@Expose
private Double popularity;
@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
private String title;
@SerializedName("video")
@Expose
private Boolean video;
@SerializedName("vote_average")
@Expose
private Double voteAverage;
@SerializedName("vote_count")
@Expose
private Integer voteCount;

private Boolean favourite;


public Movie() {
    this.favourite = false;
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
    public Movie createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Movie(in);
    }

    public Movie[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Movie[size];
    }
};

public Movie(Parcel in) {
    this.adult = in.readByte() != 0;
    this.movieId = in.readLong();
    this.backdropPath = in.readString();
    in.readList(this.genreIds, null);
    this.originalLanguage = in.readString();
    this.originalTitle = in.readString();
    this.overview = in.readString();
    this.releaseDate = in.readString();
    this.posterPath = in.readString();
    this.popularity = in.readDouble();
    this.title = in.readString();
    this.video = in.readByte() != 0;
    this.voteAverage = in.readDouble();
    this.voteCount = in.readInt();
    this.favourite = in.readByte() != 0;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeByte((byte) (this.adult ? 1 : 0));
    dest.writeLong(this.movieId);
    dest.writeString(this.backdropPath);
    dest.writeList(this.genreIds);
    dest.writeString(this.originalLanguage);
    dest.writeString(this.originalTitle);
    dest.writeString(this.overview);
    dest.writeString(this.releaseDate);
    dest.writeString(this.posterPath);
    dest.writeDouble(this.popularity);
    dest.writeString(this.title);
    dest.writeByte((byte) (this.video ? 1 : 0));
    dest.writeDouble(this.voteAverage);
    dest.writeInt(this.voteCount);
    dest.writeByte((byte) (this.favourite ? 1 : 0));
}
}
```

Error Message I get when Gson is trying to convert the result received from retrofit.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class Movie declares multiple JSON fields named id
```

It works perfectly fine when Movie doesn't extend SugarRecord.

What can I do here ?

Comment: sugar record already have a field named 'id' it holds the unique identity for the created bean

Comment: I know that the SugarRecord class has a private Long id attribute, but I thought gson would ignore it, because it is not marked as @Expose ?

Comment: what is the content of this interface? Parcelable

Comment: Do you mean by that, you want to see my implementation of the Parcelable interface ?

Comment: if its ok, maybe you declared an id property inside parcelable interface that needs to be implemented by movie class which in turn conflicts with the id   property in sugarrecord class

Comment: hey man i updated the code

Comment: How did you create your gson builder ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use @Table and extend SugarRecord at the same time (at least not in SugarORM 1.4).

[Please check my answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23069799/parsing-a-string-id-with-sugarorm-and-gson/35602175#35602175)

Comment: Does this answer the question, or is it just additional advice?

Comment: this works for me, so as far as I'm concerned this is an answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only take into account the fields you marked as @Expose, you need to call:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
```

More info here:http://www.javacreed.com/gson-annotations-example/

Answer (score 0):

Declare a private transient Long id.

That way, your id field will not be serialized.